# edit text with button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button, android-on-click

Добрый день,
Есть следующая проблема, есть поле `edit text` и `button` которые накладываются друг на друга, не могу отловить `onclicklistner` у кнопки, т.к. его перехватывает `edittext. 
Пробовал перехватить на кнопке`ontouch` но что-то тоже безрезультатно.
Внешне должно выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_padding">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/resend_sms_hint_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/not_receive_sms"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_code_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/auth_code"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/continue_SMS_login"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Код:**

```
private void initializeUI() {
    mInputCodeEditText.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
        if (actionId == R.id.continue_SMS_login || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
            attemptLogin();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    mResendSMSHintButton.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        resendSMS();
        return true;
    });

    mResendSMSHintButton.setOnClickListener(l -> {
        resendSMS();
    });

    mContinueButton.setOnClickListener(l -> attemptLogin());
}
```

Comment: Как вариант - поменяйте метами кнопку и инпутЛэйаут - так кнопка будет сверху последнего и он не будет её перекрыывать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб все гениальное просто.... Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - поменяйте меcтами в разметке `Button` и `TextInputLayout` - так кнопка будет сверху последнего и он не будет её перекрывать